# Как узнать, где находятся header файлы библиотеки?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl

`sudo apt install openssl1.1` (ubuntu 18.04)
При сборке приложения не видны header'ы, может ли быть такое что их нет в libssl1.1 и они находятся в другом пакете?

Comment: Проблема решилась установкой ``libssl-dev``

Comment: Большинство библиотек (пакетов) в ubuntu существуют в двух версиях: name и name-dev, первая - просто библиотеки для возможности запустить приложение, зависящее от пакета, а вторая (с суффиксом -dev) - пакет, включающий заголовочные файлы, позволяющий разработать приложение, использующее указанный пакет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. пакета с именем `openssl1.1` в репозитории для дистрибутива *ubuntu* версии 18.04 [просто нет](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssl1.1&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=bionic&section=all).
2. а вот пакет с именем `libssl1.1` — [имеется](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl1.1&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=bionic&section=all)
3. заголовочные файлы в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах обычно отделены от блобов в пакет с суффиксом `-dev`
4. но в указанном репозитории пакета `libssl1.1-dev` нет. вероятно, он называется как-то по-другому
5. очевидно, что пакет с заголовочными файлами должен собираться из тех же исходников, что и пакет с блобами
6. откроем страницу с описанием пакета с блобами (ссылка присутствовала на странице поиска): https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libssl1.1
7. и проследуем по ссылке на пакет с исходниками (вверху страницы: `[ Source: имя.пакета ]`): https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/openssl
8. и в списке пакетов, собираемых из этих исходников, увидим имя искомого пакета с заголовочными файлами (с суффиксом `-dev`, как и ожидалось): `libssl-dev`